# Call method after view (DOM) is updated (in Angular 2)

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-forms, angular2-directives, angular-directive

Assume that I have the following directive:

```
import {Directive, Input, OnChanges } from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: 'select[my-select]'
})
export class NbSelect implements OnChanges {

  @Input() ngModel;

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    doSomeStuffAfterViewIsUpdated();
  }

  doSomeStuffAfterViewIsUpdated() {
    console.log(jQuery('select[my-select]').val()); // this should write the new value
  }
}
```

I'm using it in somewhere in a template: `...<select my-select [(ngModel)]="someReference">...`

At some point I change the value of someReference in a component: `someReference = "newValue"`

**What is happening now:** The doSomeStuffAfterViewIsUpdated function is called before the DOM is updated. Which means the console shows the old value of the select.

**What I want:** The doSomeStuffAfterViewIsUpdated function should be called after the DOM is updated by angular, so the console shows the "newValue".

What should I use instead of ngOnChanges to make it work like I want?

Please note that the important thing here is that the code should run after the DOM update. The question is not about how can I access the new value of the element.

Thx!

Comment: Why don't you just make this a component? Also, why are you mixing in jQuery like that; Angular has its own functionality for DOM manipulation.

Comment: jQuery is there to show that we want to do some post processing by an independent library. Why using a component instead of a directive should solve the problem?

Comment: Is this what you want, ngAfterViewChecked? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html

Comment: Almost. The problem with ngAfterViewChecked is that it's called very often. Any interaction with the element (pl :hover) triggers it. I'm looking for a solution that runs only if the property that is bound to the ngModel has changed.

Comment: Is this not what you're looking for?
 `ngAfterViewInit` -
 https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/AfterViewInit-class.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late to the party, but since I had a similar problem and a probable solution, I thought I'd share:

What you're looking for is [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver));
I solved a very similar issue with a directive similar to this (simplified for... simplicity? :P):

```
ngOnChanges() {
    this.observer = new MutationObserver(() => { this.methodToCall() });
    this.observer.observe(this.elRef.nativeElement, this.observerOptions); // See linked MDN doc for options
}

private methodToCall(): void {
    this.observer.disconnect();
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if(this.observer) { 
        this.observer.disconnect(); 
        this.observer = undefined;
    }
}
```

The MutationObserver callback will be triggered when either an attribute, children, etc is modified in the DOM (or added, deleted, etc)

It is possible you won't need the `ngOnChanges` at all depending on your use case and it would make the code a bit cleaner too.